# Should I use ANSI Encoding with XML ISO-8859-1?

Tags: xml, powershell, character-encoding

I need to use PowerShell to process an XML file which specifies in its heading that it is encoded with ISO 8851-1.

What is required :

> After processing the XML must still be openable by the windows
>   application which has generated it, so processing must still give an
>   XML compatible with ISO 8851-1.

As I understand Windows "ANSI" is an extension of ISO 8859. PowerShell `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` have ANSI option. Did I understand well?

Comment: "ANSI" in this context is not really well-defined. Where it refers to CP 1252; yes, that is defined as a superset of ISO-8859-1. Where it refers to another single-byte encoding, things will usually work tranaparently as long as no transcoding is involved. For other scenarios, there can be no guarantees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When processing XML files with PowerShell you should read the files like this:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.xml'
```

and save them like this:

```
$xml.Save('C:\path\to\output.xml')
```

That should automatically take care of the encoding. If not, you can enforce an encoding by using a [`StreamWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
$filename = 'C:\path\to\output.xml'
$encoding = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('iso-8859-1')
$writer = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($filename, $false, $encoding)
$xml.Save($writer)
$writer.Close()
$writer.Dispose()
```

Comment: If I do not set encoding it won't be compatible with the application

Comment: I maked as good answer. But can you refine ASCII is 7 bit, ISO 8851 is 8 bits so It won't actually work for my case.

Comment: You can use the `GetEncoding()` method to get a specific encoding. And I suppose you actually mean ISO-8859-1, not ISO-8851-1 (which defines how to determine the moisture content in butter). See updated answer.

Comment: Your question title says 8859 and that's what makes  sense on this context.